no item provider dropdown while adding social application to django admin
Django Admin PanelI'm currently learning web development with django and while trying to add soial authentication to my project with django-allauth i was met with an error saying invalid configuration after loading the social account tag and creating a link with the provider login url tag, I though it was because i hadn't added the social applications to the django admin yet so i tried that, i went to sites and added 127.0.0.1:8000 as my link with google as the name but when i tried to add the social application, there was no item in the dropdown menu where i'm normally supposed to select a provider even though i added the allauth.socialaccount.providers for google, faceboook and microsoft
my settingss.py-->
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites', 
    #Third-Party
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.google",
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.microsoft',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    
]
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION': True,
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        },
        'OAUTH_PKCE_ENABLED': True,
    }
}
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT = 'home'

#allauth config
SITE_ID = 1

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False 
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email' 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True 
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

urls.py -->

urlpatterns = [
    #admin
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
    #User management
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.socialaccount.urls')),
]

login.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load account %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Log In{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <img class="auth-image" src="{% static "images/AuthImg.jpg" %}">
    </div>
    <div id="auth-form-box">
        <div id="log-in">
            <h2>Log In</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="form-field">
            <form class='form' method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="field">
                    <h1>Email address</h1>
                    <div class='input'>
                        {{ form.login }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <h1>Password</h1>
                    <div class='input'>
                        {{ form.password }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="remember-tick">
                    {{ form.remember }}
                    <label for="remember" class="">remember me</label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn-submit" type="submit">Log In</button>
            </form>
            {% load socialaccount %}
            <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">Sign up with Google</a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="dont-have">Don't have an account? sign in <a href="{% url "account_signup" %}">here</a></h1>
    </div>
</div>


i tried adding the client id and secret key to the codebase itself but that still did not resolve the issue and i still got an error invalid configuration error unknown provider 'google' Raised during:   allauth.account.views.LoginView

I had a similar problem. I downgraded allauth to 0.61.1 and "Google" now appeared in the menu.
pip install django-allauth==0.61.1

I raised an issue https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/3857 and the developer said I needed the to use
pip install django-allauth[socialaccount]==0.63.2

I had done this, but I tried again, this time in a fresh virtual environment and it worked.
